# Using fgets to get a username + salt + hash from a file C

Tags: c, hash, fgets, salt

I have a file that is storing a username, salt, and a fully hashed password. In a plaintext file, the salt and password is just a bunch of random characters. I need to extract the fields from the file and insert them into a linked list, but I'm running into some problems. I know fgets stops reading a line when it reaches a \n character, but for some reason it's not picking up any \n and its reading the whole file as 1 line (i think). I added "::::::::" to separate the fields. Here is the file.

> mike::::::::Éá Šú7þP)°ºËÒá|ò=³7å   M+å2÷hÂ|gÝ#ayŸ³ÔZ5W§£"û£Éù30Zä¶8«àÃê3j»Éöœ[fä)¹or!¢§yADÊñ¿5åùEB%    9oŒdi~Ê'7::::::::gÜnmë !5ªv?NPÐæP×ŸÎ*
>
> ken::::::::^ú«G7áŽzŽüÜÄÍÊ»-Mýeßleõ¥;å€üÛ"Š€Ž9
>   RÃæ«Aæž
>   ý| ÙE|"€'Å"æ@Jre    QÈGúz­6õîxK1ÉÔæBkDáwœò²E:"ÀÃ¥H\â;kÕ3::::::::M¥÷é?`;Ä?p÷÷
>   7²ìÆÖäM%Ç

This is the function I'm using

```
void loadFileIntoList (char * filename, FILE* fp){
    unsigned char * hashed;
    unsigned char * salt;
    char * username;
    char line[3000];

if (fp == NULL){
    printf("file could not be opened");
}


while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){


    username = strtok(line,  "::::::::");


    salt = (unsigned char *)strtok(NULL, "::::::::");


    hashed = (unsigned char *)strtok(NULL, "::::::::");

               //user, pass, salt, hashed. just putting in "" for pass
    addAccount(username, "", salt, hashed);



}




fclose(fp);


}
```

The size of line is probably the reason why it's only looping once, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know how large it should be.

I think I need another set of "::::::::" after the first hash, or before the second username. But here is my output (just printing line, user, salt, and hash)

Any insight on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Unless the salt and hash are encoded as printable characters, you'll need to read the file as binary. Which means you can't use `fgets`.

Comment: Note there is no point passing `"::::::::"` to `strtok`, it does not work like `strstr`. One `":"` is enough, but your second input contains a single `":"` anyways, which will break your intention, no mattter how many of them you put in the delimiter string.

Comment: its very odd to see raw binary in a text file, normally these would be base64 encoded (like PEM files). BTW you are missing things from your source - like opening the file

Comment: I open the file before I call this function and just pass in the fp and filename. I'll look into reading a binary file

Comment: So why do you pass the filename? Check the file opened *at the point of opening* not some time later.

Comment: looking back I guess I don't really need to pass the filename in. it was just a way for me to distinguish between the persistent file created when the server executes, and the file provided as an argument (if it is provided...)

Comment: how can i extract the fields from a binary file?

Comment: To answer that question, I would need to know the exact format of the file. But generally, binary files have fixed-length records that you read into an array with `fread`. You can also read the file one byte at a time with `fgetc`.